# Share flowplayer on facebook wall not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, flowplayer

I would like to share my own flowplayer on facebook wall. To keep things simple, I copy the demo page by flowplayer to our server.

The demo page on flowplayer website is

http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/fbshare.html

It works pretty good. When I click to share this page, the flowplayer embedded to my facebook wall. So I copy the page, change the URL inside the page and upload to my server.

http://testing.org.in/fbvideo/test.html

When I want to share the this page to facebook, facebook only treats it as a normal page and no embedded flowplayer on the wall after I shared the page.

I try to use the opengraph debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftesting.org.in%2Ffbvideo%2Ftest.html

It shows a warning message.

> Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.blacktrash.org/img/fliegetot.png' will be used instead.

However, that thumbnail the warning mention is not the thing I would like to share and specific on the og:image. It seems that facebook just omit the flowplayer config specified on the og tag.

Could anyone can tell me what's wrong of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your page is that you're missing the "og:video:secure_url" meta tag.
Without the secure url of the video FB won't create an embedded video post.
You'll need an https server hosting a copy of both the video and the image you want on your post.

Lately FB seems to reject small thumbs so if you have any problems with the image just use a bigger one.